# Why does Modern Warfare 3 download twice on Steam?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

MW3 appears to be downloading twice on Steam.

First, single player which is downloading 14GB (which is currently at ~7GB). I'm hoping it will download multiplayer too, but it's not, and I have to download multiplayer which is ~7GB also, and it's downloading 14GB again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is the same as with MW2, this is just a glitch in how Steam represents those download. It is actually downloading everything only once, but lists it twice in the Downloads view.

That's also why you can't pick a separate download folder, because they're the same.